# Set user role after user registration (not via hook_user_presave)

Tags: 7, users

I want to assign roles to a user after the user registers, or when a user is created by another user. Normally this can be done with hook_user_presave() but the problem I am running into now is that there is some other logic in the platform that is synchronizing users from a third system. While creating those users hook_user_presave() is also called and the roles are assigned as well. But that should NOT happen in this case but only when a user register himself or another admin user is doing that. The new role should only be assigned after submitting the user_register_form.

My idea now is to add a custom submit handler to the user_register_form and set the user role there. The code is simple:

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
        $form['#submit'][] = 'mymod_register_submit';
    }
}
```

And for the custom submit handler:

```
function mymod_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $account = user_load($form_state['values']['uid']);

    $account->roles[123] = true;

    user_save($account);
}
```

I could not find a problem while testing that but I am afraid that this is not the way it should be solved since I am actually saving a user account while saving a user account.

The question now: Can I solve the problem like this or is there a better way?

Cheers,
J

Comment: Have you ever tried "add rules"?-[Rule Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) 1. Go to /config/rules, add a new rule. You might see "After saving a new user account" option. 2. Then, add a new action "add user role".

Comment: I second the rules route form @jmu. Other option to toy with is `hook_user_login` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7.x

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Maybe I was not completely clear. I want to have those roles assigned only if the user creates his own account or when the account is generated by an admin. The role should NOT be assigned if users are created another way like for example creating a user with user_save() programatically.
Rules would apply to both scenarios and using hook_user_login does not allow me to find out in which way the user was created.
I will edit the question slightly.